# Where can I find dskprobe.exe for Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, partition, data-recovery, diskmanagement

As the question suggests, where can I find dskprobe.exe for Windows Server 2012 R2?  I need dskprobe to recover a deleted partition and I can not find the application anywhere on my server and looking for it on the web seems to be a very hard task.  Did they do away with it?  It so, will old versions built for old OSs still work on 2012 R2?

This is how I'm trying to recover my partition that was deleted as cited on [this microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245725).

> **To Recover a Deleted NTFS Volume**
>
> 1. Re-create the exact same volume but choose not to format it. This may
>      be difficult if you do not remember the exact size you had created
>      originally, especially because the Disk Management snap-in tends to
>      round partition sizes.
> 2. Using Dskprobe.exe, recover the backup boot
>      sector for the NTFS volume from the end of the volume. Because it is a
>      dynamic volume you may need to use Dmdiag.exe to help find the backup
>      boot sector, or search for it by using Dskprobe.exe (on the Tools
>      menu, click Search Sectors).
> 3. After rewriting the NTFS boot sector,
>      quit Dskprobe.
> 4. In Disk Management, click Rescan Disks on the Action
>      menu. This should mount the volume for immediate use.

Comment: Are you recovering the system partition?

Comment: No, this is just a data drive.  It's a 3 disk system.  The system partition is alive and stable.  I'm currently using that server to do these tasks.  I just can't find that EXE.

Comment: Seems like dskprobe is (was) for re-creating the boot sector.  If you don't have a boot sector, the remaining steps would apply.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need to do.  :)  I just need to find a copy of that app.  Is Windows Server 2003 SP2 that latest OS to have it?  I did find the latest version of it in the Windows Support Tools located on the Windows Server 2003 SP2 disk.  Is that the best place to find it?

Comment: Why are you copying a boot sector if you don't have a boot sector?

Comment: I'm not trying to COPY anything.  I'm trying to recreate the volume's file-system boot sector (sector-0 of the volume).  So that I can bring the partition back to life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get dskprobe.exe AKA Disk Probe by Microsoft, you need to get an old OS package and do a few manual things to make it available to you.

(1) Download the Windows XP SP2 Support Tools from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546).

(2) Extract the contents of the EXE (WindowsXPKB838079SupportToolsENU.
exe) to a location on "C:\" such as "C:\tools" or any place you might like.

(3) If you try to run support tools installer (suptools.msi) by double clicking on it you will receive an error (shown below).

[image]

(3a) Use the following command to expand the cab files for use...

```
C:\> cd c:\tools
C:\tools> expand support.cab C:\tools -F:DSK*
```

(4) Right click on dskprobe.exe and **Run As Administrator**.  You should see Disk Probe show up as the image below...

[image]

Furthermore if you are seeking to do the same thing I'm trying to do and need help understanding how Disk Probe works (it's not exactly obvious), then check out [this article](https://support2.microsoft.com/?id=kb;en-us;q153973) and read the following area...
**Recovering Bootsectors of Primary Partitions.**

Comment: 03-08-2021 tried to follow link to download XP SP2 Support tools and it no longer works (not really a surprise since they're XP files and it's 2021 - Microsoft no longer supports). Does anyone have an alternative link to get this file?